# Test the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$ for convergence or divergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to test $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$ for convergence or divergence.

I thought to compare $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$ to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ as i reasoned that for the first series the term $\frac{1}{n}$ in the exponent can be at most $1$ and for all $n\gt1$ that term will be a fraction, hence the exponent of $n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ will be at most $n^2$. The second series is a convergent p-series as $p=2 \gt1$. However, this does not really help me as i see now that ${n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \lt n^2$ and a smaller denominator means that $\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$ will actually be bigger than $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Use limit-comparison with $\sum_n 1/n$.

Answer (score 2):

You can see inductively that for every natural number $n\geq 1$ you have $n\leq2^n$, so $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq 2$. Use this for a comparison test for your series.